# Objective-C - ulong to uint32

Tags: objective-c, uint32, ulong

How can i convert an ulong to uint32? A simple cast is not working. What works for me is converting the long to a string and then again parsing the string to an int.

However this seems really wrong. Is there any better way?

Comment: What do you mean by "A simple cast is not working" exactly ? What is the exact compiler error message or run-time problem that you are encountering ?

Comment: Casting a ulong with the value 75 results in an uint32 with the value of 2147483647.

Comment: From where are you getting the type `ulong`? What is its definition? What does your cast look like?

Comment: The value 75 fits into a `unit32` without problem (even a `uint16` or `uint8`) so something is very wrong with your code.

Answer (score 4):

Like Paul R said, not sure what you mean by "simple cast".
Both of the following are working fine for me (and, note, I'm testing with a ULONGLONG).

1. Direct cast:

   `unsigned long long val1 = (unsigned long long)75;

   UInt32 val2 = (UInt32)val1;

   NSLog( @"%qu, %lu", num1, num2 );

   // OUTPUTS: 75, 75`
2. Using NSNumber:

   `NSNumber* val1 = [NSNumber numberwithUnsignedLongLong:75];

   NSNumber* val2 = [NSNumber numberwithUnsignedInteger:[val1 usignedIntegerValue]];

   NSLog( @"%qu, %u", [num1 unsignedLongLongValue], [num2 unsignedIntegerValue]];

   // OUTPUTS: 75, 75`